# What is the relationship between completeness and local compactness?

Tags: general-topology, soft-question

On the one hand, $\mathbb{Q}$ is neither [complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_metric_space) (as a metric space) nor [locally compact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locally_compact_space) (as a topological space). On the other hand, $\mathbb{R}$ is both complete and locally compact.

My question is, what is the relationship between completeness and local compactness? e.g. Does one imply the other?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the [Baire space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_%28set_theory%29) $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ (which is homeomorphic to the space of irrationals) is a completely metrizable space which is not locally compact (in fact all compact subsets of $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ have empty interior).

While locally compact metric spaces may not be complete (for example, as in Brad's answer, the open unit interval $(0,1)$ under the usual metric), these spaces will always be *completely metrizable*.  There are at least two ways to see this result:

1. Every locally compact metric space will be an open subset of its completion, and every G$_\delta$ subset of a complete metric space is completely metrizable.
2. Every locally compact completely regular space is Čech-complete (*i.e.*, is a G$_\delta$ subset of its Stone-Čech (or any other) compactification), and a metric space is completely metrizable iff it is Čech-complete.

Comment: So if a topological space is both locally compact, and also metrizable, then it is also completely metrizable? Or is there a subtlety I am missing?

Comment: @user18921: Yes, every locally compact metrizable space is completely metrizable.

Answer (score 4):

Neither implies the other. In addition to the examples you give, there are metric spaces which are complete and not locally compact (e.g. an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space) and metric spaces which are locally compact and not complete (e.g. the open interval $(0,1)$).

Comment: But locally compact metric spaces should be completely metrizable, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @AsafKaragila wouldn't one need second countability or something similar?

Comment: @Alexander: I don't see why. Completeness is a local property.

Comment: A locally compact metric space will be open in its completion, and will therefore be itself completely metrizable (being a G$_\delta$ subset of a complete metric space).

Comment: Thanks, I did only know about the 'summing up normalized distances w.r.t. a compact base'-construction.

Comment: @Asaf: completeness  is not a local property.

Comment: @Georges: How would you think about a local property?

Comment: @Asaf. You made a statement and you should say what you mean by it, not I . Anyway all manifolds are locally the same and some are complete, some not, so that I don't think that what you say is correct under any interpretation.

Comment: @Georges: Thinking about it some more, it was probably a poor choice of terms "local". But the idea is that completeness happens at very small distances. Moreover, I often interchange completeness with completely metrizable in my mind, and the above comment you refer was more about the latter than the former.

Comment: By the way, I would like to remind all users that completeness is not a topological concept at all, since a complete topological space may be homeomorphic  to a non-complete one: think of $\mathbb R$ and $(0,1)$. Completeness makes sense for a metric space (and I don't mean metrizable space: the metric must be part of the structure) or more generally for a uniform space. Uniform spaces form a rather *passé* structure, which can still  be found in Bourbaki (but probably not in many other other places) and due to André Weil.